# Как получить конкретную строку из БД?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть **БД** с некими строками. Столбцы: `name` и `family`.

У меня **3** Пети. Нужно получить данные **только второго**(например). Причём искать с помощью `WHERE name LIKE "Петя"`.

Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, мне запрос.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: А как отличить второго от первого ? Ведь в БД нет такого понятия как "порядок записей", результаты могут возвращаться в любом порядке и следовательно "вторым" может оказаться любой. Необходим точный критерий, в виде указания сортировки. А когда ее укажете, можете применить `limit 1,1` что бы запрос вернул именно вторую запись

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно выбрать 2 запись оператором LIMIT.

```
SELECT name, family FROM myTable WHERE name LIKE "%Петя%" LIMIT 1, 1
```

Из всех "Петь" возьмешь одну запись пропустив первую. 
[Подробнее можешь тут почитать](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html).